# Binary Search Tree

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

My professor posted some review questions for the final exam. And I can't seem to find the answers for it. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Consider a binary tree of n nodes:
a. What is the minimal and maximal number of leaf nodes?
b. What is the minimal and maximal value of the height?
c. How many pointers are used by the tree (not counting the null pointers, and assuming we do not keep a field that stores the parent)?

*d. What is the worst care running time for inserting n nodes into a (initially empty) binary search tree?

Comment: You should go talk to the professor and see if you can get what he was leading you to understand from these questions.  Maybe he can shed some light on the overall concept he's looking for.

Comment: Do you understand what a binary tree is? If so try putting some numbers to check if you can figure out answers like n=3, 4 etc

Comment: The Prof did not say "Balanced Binary Tree", and the worst-case Binary Tree degenerates to a....  Bueler?  Bueler?  Anybody?

Comment: I know this is a really old question, but just in case anyone is still looking for an answer... you may want to take a look at his post on how to implement AVL trees from scratch. https://medium.com/amiralles/mastering-data-structures-in-ruby-avl-trees-6206bf2035e0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The maximum number of leaves is ceil(n / 2). The minimum number is 1
- The maximum height is n. The minimum is floor(log_2(n))

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing various trees on a paper and see what you get. Remember that a binary tree is defined as a tree where each node may have 0 (in which case it is a leaf), 1 or 2 children. For your question you should examine the very unbalanced case of 1 child per node.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

If you're trying to maximize the number of leaves, you want as few internal nodes as possible (and the reverse if you're trying to minimize the number of leaves). How can you accomplish that?

To get a tree of maximal height, you'll put as few nodes in each level as possible. How can you do that? Conversely, for the minimum height, what is the maximum number of nodes you can put at each level?

How many ways are there to get to each node of a tree? Thus, how many pointers do you need?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're either coding in C or C++.

a. A node, if the structure is defined like this:
struct node { struct node *left, *right; };
You can observe that the structure can either have 0, 1, or 2 leaves. So, the max is 2, min is 0 leaves.

b.Minimal height is zero, in which would only contain the root node. Note that the root node does not count as a height of 1. It's also called depth at times.
Here is an algorithm for the height:

```
    int height(struct node *tree) 
    { 
    if (tree == NULL) return 0;
    return 1 + max (height (tree->left), height (tree->right)); 
    }
```

Read more: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_find_out_the_height_of_a_Binary_Search_Tree#ixzz1NIB17SkL

c. Pardon me if I take this the worng way, but I'm assuming if we mapped this out on a piece of paper, we'd be trying to find the number of "links" that we would use? In that case, it'd simply be the number of nodes in the tree -1 for root node. This algorithm found on this page http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1147688.htm can help you: check if root is null, then pass the left and right nodes as parameters into the function.

```
int countnodes(Node* root)
{
    if (root == null || k<=0)
    {
      return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + count(root.left,k-1) + count(root.right,k-1);
    }
}
// remember to subtract one at the end.
int totalnodes = countnodes(root) - 1;
```

d. The time complexity for best case is O(nlogn) where n is the number of nodes to insert. The worst case, is O(n). It is directly linear.

If you have any other questions just google it, there's plenty of things to know about binary search trees. But most of it is simply recursion that you can learn in 30 seconds.

I hope this helps. Good luck on your exam! I had mine a few months ago. ;)